# Parent div not expanding with children, why not?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

My parent div is not expanding to hold the height of its children. I read that:
position: absolute;
float: any;

Both ruin this. The thing is that the div that does hold absolute elements does expand, but the div holding this, position: relative;, div is not expanding. I'd add a link for viewing but my page is not on a server yet (I am viewing it directly from HTML in Firefox.)

Clarification: It is the .banner_section div that is refusing to expand.

My HTML

```
<header>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
        <div class="menu_section">
            <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button"></input>
                <ul id="menu">
                  <li><a href="index.html">HEM</a>
                    <li><a href="hudvard.html">HUDVÅRD</a>
                    <li><a href="fotvard.html">FOTVÅRD</a>
                    <li><a href="massage.html">MASSAGE</a>
                    <li><a href="tejpning.html">TEJPNING</a>
                    <li><a href="varumarken.html">VÅRA VARUMÄRKEN</a>
                    <li><a href="omoss.html">OM OSS</a>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">ONLINEBOKNING</a>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.html">TELEFONBOKNING</a>
                </ul> 
        </div>
    <div class="banner_section">
      <div class="rslides_container">
        <ul class="rslides">
          <li><img src="images/index_banner.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/fot_banner.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/massage_banner.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/tejpning_banner.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/hudvard_banner.jpg" /></li>
          <li><img src="images/omoss_banner.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
              auto: true, speed: 1500, timeout: 2000, nav: true,
            });
          });
        </script>
    </div>
  </header>
```

My CSS

```
.banner_section{
    background-color: #83AFB4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 269px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.rslides_container {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
}
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

.rslides1_nav {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 61px;
    width: 38px;
    background: url("themes.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    margin-top: -45px;
}
.prev{
    background: red;
}

.next{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Well firstly your html needs tidying up. None of your menu li list items are closed. </li>

Comment: Updated fiddle here using online images http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/x6qmtyqo/1/ now what is the issue?

Comment: Your fiddle is working now though. 
The images fully fit within its parent as you switch images by clicking the red button on the side. It just doesn't scroll to it.

Comment: @Iharby Ooh. That's embarrassing for me :S Good catch, thank you!

Comment: The fiddle is indeed "working" but the problematic div, .banner_section is still all flat. I have updated the question with a clarification that this is the div in question.

Comment: I am not really sure what you want. It looks like the slider is responsive and that is important, yes? I have added a min-height to the banner to show the base. But do you want to set the height for all images, or use overflow-hidden or something to stop the whole page jumping when different sized images are loaded? http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/x6qmtyqo/2/

Comment: @IthilonethMoonsnow OK, I think the answer you want is clearfix. So I have posted a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK check this out.

I added clearfix to the parent banner and I have a fiddle working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/x6qmtyqo/3/embedded/result/

This is the clearfix css:

```
.clearfix:after { 
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
.clear { overflow:hidden; clear:both; height:1px; margin:-1px 0px 0px 0px; font-size:1px; }
.clear-simple {clear:both; }
```

Then I added clearfix class to your banner_section, so:

```
<div class="banner_section clearfix">
```

Let me know if that works for you (it adds a margin below the images too, but you have that specified in your css).

Comment: Thank you for you help Iharby. I managed to solve the problem earlier today and some of your suggestions really helped. I can't say for certain what it was that I did that worked, I just know that between one change or another it started doing what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To make the parent depending to the child div, you have to make the parent

```
postion:relative
```

and set the width and the height of the child at whatever you want, the parent will adjust to it.

Lets see the demo:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jorge9200/pucrtgxm/)

Comment: This demo is indeed all working but I cannot see how I can use it to address my problem.